# Print the elements that occur more than once in a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays

Print the elements that occur more than once in a sorted array.

Input Format
The input consists of two lines:

The first line contains a single integer N, representing the size of the array (1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5).

The second line contains N space-separated integers, A[1], A[2], ..., A[N], representing the elements of the array (-10^9 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10^9).

Output Format
Print the repeating elements in a single line, separated by a space, or -1 if no element is repeating.

Sample Inputs & Outputs
Sample Input 1
8
1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5
Sample Output 1
3 4

.

Output Format
Print
the repeating elements in a single line, separated by a space, or -1 if no element is repeating.
Sample Inputs & Outputs
Sample Input 1
8
1 2 3 3 4 4 4 5
Sample Output 1
3 4

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question, showing what you've tried and using your attempt to help write a better and more site-appropriate question. As written, it could be seen by some as a no-effort homework dump, putting it at risk of being closed. If you improve it as per the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), tour and [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852) links, then it has a better chance of remaining open and being answered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "pointer" to the start of the array, just an int initialized to 0.
Now you have two possible cases, either the number you're currently pointing at is equal to the next one, in which case it's duplicated, or it's not and you can skip it.
If it's not equal skip it, otherwise create a new temporary pointer and loop until it reaches a number that is different than the one pointed at by the original pointer, or you reached the end of the array.
pseudocode:

```py
ind = 0
while (ind<(n-1)):
    if arr[ind]==arr[ind+1]:
        print(temp, end = " ")
    temp = ind+1
    while temp<n and arr[temp]!=arr[ind]: temp+=1 #if not duplicate this will stop imediatly
    ind = temp
```